# php class extension dynamically

Tags: php, inheritance

Below is example I want to extend each class with previously included class , I know this:

**Base.php**

```
class Base {

 protected function foo()
 {
     echo 'I am baseclass'; 
 }

}
```

**Child1.php**

```
class Child1 {

 protected function foo()
 {
     echo 'I am child1'; 
 }

}
```

**Child2.php**

```
class Child2 {

 protected function foo()
 {
     echo 'I am child2'; 
 }

}
```

My final class will be **Mymodule**

**Mymodule.php**

Which should do below without manually extending:

```
Child1 extends Base,
Child2 extends Child1
Child2 extends Mymodule
```

Like this possible dynamically ? because I have 11  class like this, I finally need `Mymodule` please guide me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extend `Base` without writing "`extends Base`"? I wonder why.

Comment: Yes, you are right I have many files I want to extend each with previously loaded file

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov : I hope you got what I meant to say, I don't want to write every time  "extends", but last module class should load each class by name (I will give list of files in array) and should extend each one with previous one.

Comment: Inheritance is a compile-time feature. AFAIK, it is impossible to extend a class at run-time without forcing compilation with `eval`, `include`, `require`, or similar functions. Besides, it is doubtful that the feature would be even useful, as it introduces implicit (error-prone) behavior.

Comment: It takes less time to write `extends blah-blah-blah` 11 times than writing the question on SO, reading all the comments and answers just to find out there is no magically way a software can know what you are thinking. Even if you don't want to write `extends` so many times you still have to tell the compiler which class extends what, otherwise you won't get what you want. Extending *"each class with previously included class"* is vague, fragile and not practical. How would you extend both `Class1` **and** `Class2` from `Base` this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that Child2 class extends Child1 and mymodule classes. Php does not allow multiple inheritance, so a class can only extend one class.

Php 5.4 introduced a feature called Traits. It allows a class to inherit multiple classes which are defined as traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php. If you defined Child1 and mymodule classes as traits then you can extend Child2 class from both Child1 and mymodule